# How to rename all files and directories in current folder?

Tags: command-line, bash, find, regex, rename

I have a directory structure like this:

```
./
  whatever/
    foos_whatever.ext
  something/
    foo/
      1.ext
      2.ext
  another/
    foo.ext
```

I want to rename all files **and** directories that contain `foo`. I would like to replace `foo` with `bar`.

Here is what I am trying:

```
[naomi ~/app]$ find . -name '*foo*' -exec f={} && mv -v f ${f/foo/bar} \;
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way I think yould be this :

```
find -name "*foo*" -exec rename s/foo/bar/ {} \;
```

or with xargs, if you have a lot of files to rename :

```
find -name "*foo*" | xargs -I '{}' rename s/foo/bar/ '{}'
```

However, the problem with that, is if you have a directory structure that looks something like this :

```
.
|-- fooDir
|   |-- foo.txt
|   `-- abc
`-- foo2
```

It will fail at renaming foo.txt, because it will first rename fooDir into barDir, and then claim it no longer finds "fooDir/foo.txt"

Simply re-running the command until you have no error works but it's sloppy. Another way would be to run the command in a loop, once for each level of depth of your directory tree, with the `find` options `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` set to exclude other levels, but then you have to know the depth of your directory system.

I can't think of a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use command chains like that in `-exec`, since the shell interprets them as being continuations of `find` itself. Either run the chain in a subshell, or use `rename` or `prename` to rename the file instead.

Comment: Vasquez-Abrams, I'm not very experienced with the shell. Can you show me how this would be done?

Comment: For `rename` and `prename`, see their respective man pages. For subshell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810296/bash-find-exec-and-filenames/5810316#5810316